# Website,WebApp,Responsive Site,Mobile Native App

Tags: user-expectation, responsive-design, mobile-web, experience, native-app

So there is lot of debate going on in world wide web about websites taking over mobile native apps.
Well it stays subjective.

But i came up with this case recently.

So we have a website that has a lot of data of all companies.
Where there are many categories and lot of small small informations.
So does it makes sense of going for a native app.
or
Making our current website responsive.

When should we prefer not going to native app.
what will be the use cases.

Answer (score 1):

What you need here is a little Market Research.

It sounds like there are no technological factors that would bind you to building an app - you don't need to use any of the device's specialist hardware to complete your processes.

At the same time there's nothing really to stop you from building the functionality from your website into an app.

This is the point where you need to ask your users what they would prefer. You could ask them questions like "How important is it for you to be able to use this service without an internet connection?", "What do you use the service for?", "How often do you use the service?", "Where are you when you use the service most?", etc.

Focus on finding questions that relate to the advantages and disadvantages of using we-based and app-based versions of *your* service. If you choose your questions carefully, you should be able to gauge the value of developing an app from the answers you get without actually asking "Do you want this in an app?".

Comment: Problem is users here are investors & Stakeholders , cannot really test anything with them.

Comment: Product is something like crunchbase,pitchbook,mattermark .

Comment: If you actually talk to them and explain the importance of testing, they will find time to help you out. I have also had to deal with users who routinely tell you that they will not make themselves available for testing - right up until the time you actually ask them to help you improve the service they use. Investors and Stakeholders especially, have a vested interest in helping to create the best possible product. I have never met an investor or stakeholder in a product/service who wasn't willing to come in to help with improvements to that product/service.